# How to use / implement Custom SOAP Header in soap based web service

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

i want to create and consume custom web service based on soap

i am referring this link

http://www.rameshjalla.com/2012/08/aspnet-web-service-custom-soap-header.html

in the end it ask to use Custom soap header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <CustomSOAPHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </CustomSOAPHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSomething xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My question is where it is actually used ? as i cant implement in web.config like this as it gived error .Please suggest

Comment: This is used if you have Authentication on your webservice, you need to specify UserName and password for the same

Comment: i got it , but the question is where is use it / put it / auto create customer soap header ?? please suggest

Comment: This is the output of the code , you need not to put this in web.config or elsewhere.
Article is showing the output of above code.